# Can I have Siri turn off Silent Mode?

Tags: iphone

I have a fantastic iPhone case from Otterbox for my iPhone SE. After 1 1/2 years the little switch on the outside of the case, which activates/deactivates the hardware Silent Mode, broke.

I can't get to the switch without opening the case. Not practical.

Can I ask Siri to turn off Silent Mode? If I ask Siri *"silent mode off"* or *"turn off silent mode"* I get *"this is as quiet as it gets"* or *"I can't make this any quieter"*. LOL, Siri.

Is there an GUI option to turn off Silent Mode?

See
[How to put your iPhone on vibrate, ring, or silent mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208353)

EDIT: Of course I can "ask" Siri, but the real question is will Siri.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps check Do Not Disturb mode. There are multiple ways to toggle it on and off. Including using Siri. Alternatively you can enable/disable silent mode by going to settings > accessibility > touch > back tap > double-tap or triple-tap > mute. This allows you to tap on the back of your phone to toggle silent mode.

Comment: Didn't know about back tap. That's super cool. I'm so confused about all of these volume terms: mute, silent mode, volume off, but "mute" did display "silent mode" settings when activated. Perfect!